# Is there way to get how much time was taken during the last boot of OS X?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, boot

Is there way to get how long the last boot of OS X took programatically (Objective C/C)? For example last boot of OS X took 30 seconds.

Comment: The boot before last you mean?

Comment: Couldn't you just run `uptime` via `popen` and parse the output ?

Comment: Nonsense; if the OP wants the time since the last boot time then using `sysctl(3)` and getting `kern.boottime` is a way better method. https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/sysctl.3.html

Answer (score 0):

So I did this a while back to get it displayed in Geek Tool. I originally wanted it in Objective-C but it turned out to be a lot easier to do in Python:

```
import time
import subprocess
import re

currentTime = time.time()
p = subprocess.Popen('sysctl kern.boottime', shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
for line in p.stdout.readlines():
    bootTime = line
    break

p = re.compile('\d+')
bootTime = p.findall(bootTime)[0]
uptime = int(currentTime) - int(bootTime)
```

Not exactly what you are after, but you could call this script from Objective-C, or as you can see, the command you call is `sysctl kern.boottime`, which returns something like: `kern.boottime: { sec = 1382617144, usec = 0 } Thu Oct 24 13:19:04 2013`

Comment: And did you look at `sysctl(3)`?

Comment: Please read topic again. I need how much time took last OS X startup process. (NOT when was last boot). E.g. last OS X startup took 10 seconds only.

Comment: kern.boottime doesn't have such info.

Comment: You should probably make your question more clear. It sounds like you want to know the time since last boot.